# Graphics card probably shorted out

Tags: windows-7, audio, graphics-card, troubleshooting

My motherboard: Asus P8B75-M LX

I plugged in my speakers to the audio jack same connection as a earphone. When I plugged it in there was a buzzing noise coming out of the speakers. When I put the earphone in no there was no buzzing noise, but for some reason the system turned off and turned itself back on. After that the gaming GeForce graphics card wouldn't work. It was dead, so I had no display at all. I disconnected it and am now using the standard graphics.

The audio jack at the back of the system seems to work fine, but the front audio jack also sounds distorted and low.

What happened? It was all fine this morning. When I came home and switched the computer on, that's when it all started. The graphics card no longer works. Could it be because of the motherboard? I doubt it, but with my luck maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the motherboard is more likely the culprit that the video card.  I have a similar problem, without the buzzing, and it was the video card.  The buzzing sound could just be an unshielded/poorly shielded speaker cable.

I have so many cables behind PC that if I unplugged the speaker cable my speakers make a buzzing sound due to the fact my cable acts like an antenna and picks up the surrounding RF/EMI.

Comment: Could be that I try disabling the front port  see if that fixes it and the card id brand new Thanks ;)